# problem in use pi_face_tracker

Tags: ros-groovy, rosbridge

[image: Rosanswers logo]

I want to run the pi_face_tracker on my ROS, however, in the step of "rosdep install pi_vision", I always get error like:
ERROR: the following packages/stacks could not have their rosdep keys resolved
to system dependencies:
pi_face_tracker_gui: Missing resource rosbridge

ROS path [0]=/opt/ros/groovy/share/ros
ROS path [1]=/home/tishiba/catkin_ws/src/beginner_tutorials/rosbridge_suite
ROS path [2]=/home/tishiba/catkin_ws/src/beginner_tutorials/pi_vision
ROS path [3]=/home/tishiba/catkin_ws/src/beginner_tutorials/pi_vision
ROS path [4]=/home/tishiba/catkin_ws/src/beginner_tutorials/pi_vision
ROS path [5]=/home/tishiba/catkin_ws/src/beginner_tutorials/uvc_cam
ROS path [6]=/home/tishiba/catkin_ws/src/beginner_tutorials
ROS path [7]=/home/tishiba/catkin_ws/src
ROS path [8]=/opt/ros/groovy/share
ROS path [9]=/opt/ros/groovy/stacks
anybody know how to solve the problem?

---

[Originally posted](https://answers.ros.org/question/59537/problem-in-use-pi_face_tracker/) by [DavidXiong](https://answers.ros.org/users/4516/davidxiong/) on ROS Answers with karma: 3 on 2013-03-29

Post score: 0

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[image: Rosanswers logo]

Hi @DavidXiong,

The pi_face_tracker_gui package (created by Scott Bell) requires the older Version 1 rosbridge package which can be found [here](http://www.ros.org/wiki/rosbridge).  It looks like you have rosbridge_suite installed which I believe is the newer Version 2 rosbridge.  So you can either install the Version 1 rosbridge or just comment out the  line in the manifest.xml for the pi_face_tracker_gui assuming you can do without the GUI for now.  (The rest of the pi_face_tracker package does not require the GUI.)

--patrick

http://www.pirobot.org

---

Originally posted by [Pi Robot](https://answers.ros.org/users/30/pi-robot/) with karma: 4046 on 2013-03-29

This answer was **ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 1

---

#### Original comments

**Comment by [DavidXiong](https://answers.ros.org/users/4516/davidxiong/) on 2013-03-29**:
@Pi Robot, Thank U patrick, I do installed the newer Version 2 rosbridge,and after I comment out the  line in the manifest.xml for the pi_face_tracker_gui, I can make the step "rosmake pi_vision" , however, in the next step--"roslaunch ros2opencv openni_node.launch",  I got the error like:

**Comment by [DavidXiong](https://answers.ros.org/users/4516/davidxiong/) on 2013-03-29**:
silly number limited!  I got the error like:             error loading  tag:
file does not exist [/opt/ros/groovy/share/openni_camera/info/openni_params.yaml]
XML is    CAN U TELL ME WHAT TO DO NOW? THX!